# when Updating & selecting from huge table where the id start from 30000 timing more than 2min

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008-r2, latency

Kindly i have a database containing **2 tables**: first one with more than 2 million records
and the second a history table of the first one.
when we are trying to do a select or update and the ID (primary Key) is more than 30 000 the query is taking more than 1 min to be executed.
if i do a truncate and import the Data and the id starts from 1 the query take 1 sec.
Kindly why the **latency when the ID > 30 000** and any other solution?    Indexes done on: 1 for PK another one on date and another one on field priority integer
if i do a simple select top 10 * from table1 i have the latency of 2 min
PS: lots of transaction are done in the same time on the first table (select , insert , update & delete)
Thank you,

Comment: You need to add more details to your question. The table structures including existing indexes, the queries you execute and the query plans you get for your queries.

Comment: So you have bad performance for for queries where ID > 30000 **and** for a `select top 10 ..` query without an order by clause. Did I understand your issue correctly? Is the server otherwise very busy? Do you have long running transactions from other clients? What about the query plans? What do they tell you?

Comment: `set Transaction isolation level read uncommitted`,    `with (nolock)` etc.

Comment: Have you try performing some maintenance tasks (like vacumm on postgresql)? One thing that comes to mind that can be causing some performance degradation issue is that records with ID above 30000 have references to other tables (though it shouldn't take that long). What I can suggest, nonetheless, is that you run some maintenance routine a see what happens. If problem persists, test your queries on a mirror server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are suffering from lock contention, you have essentially two choices:

1. Stop all other activity while you do the query. This will guarantee a consistent view of the data. (Technically other steps are required to guarantee consistency with other tables). You can do this by specifying the `with (TABLOCKX)` query hint.

   (You can also use the "serialized" transaction isolation level, which will progressively lock the table from end to end as you read it. You can do clever things with indexes to make this less painful, but that qualifies as "advanced").
2. Allow other activity to continue, but accept that the answer you get may be inconsistent with activity which took place while the query was in progress. That is, rows which were being added during the query may, or may not, be included, and rows which were being deleted during the query may, or may not, be included, and rows which were being updated, may, or may not, have the previous or subsequent values. In addition, you may find that some later values are included while some earlier values are not, so it won't be temporally consistent. You can do this with the `with (NOLOCK)` hint.

   (You can also use the "read uncommitted" transaction isolation level. Generally it is easier just to specify NOLOCK when you need it).

Depending on what you are doing, either option might be best. If you want to provide rough numbers, or a sort of rolling "top 10" for reporting/monitoring purposes, use option 2. If you must provide something like an accounting number, bank balance, etc, so you must have a checkpoint where you know the exact correct number at an instant in time, use option 1. This is rare - if in doubt you probably want option 2.

The "in between" options, read committed, read snapshot etc, are rarely actually needed, in spite of being the default, and should probably only be used if you understand the situation well enough to know whether you need them or not.

Comment: the problem is that i have different apps doing select from the same table but the where differ from app to app for example the first app do a select * from table1 where x=1 the app 2 do a select * from table1 where x=2 and after the select the app treat each record and do update on it.  everything work fine till the id field becomes more that 30000 and we start getting the latency  if i reset the id to start from 1 the latency disappear.  why i'm having this latency when the ID is big

Comment: @user1199175, you are not making sense. How can a table with 2 million rows have ID < 30000? Surely ID will be >= 2000000?

Comment: @user1199175, "when we are trying to do a select or update and the ID (primary Key) is more than 30 000 the query is taking more than 1 min to be executed". So you mean when ID < 30000 it will take less than 1 min, no?

Comment: the ID start from 1 till 2million. when doing select Top 1000 using query designer its take more than 1min so how come if i do select all.